# Upgrade flutter in an unfinished project?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a project and as I run the project there is a log that tells me to upgrade my current flutter version. I then upgrade my flutter version and then after that the app became laggy.

My question is, is it recommendable to not update flutter version when you are working on an unfinished project and then update the flutter version after the project is finished?

Thank you for your time on answering. Cheers.

Comment: In my experience, I would say the earlier you upgrade the better it is. Maybe right now, you won't face any breaking changes, but you might face them if you have more code.
In my case, the upgrade to newer flutter versions went smoothly

Comment: Well I guess I just have to check for improvement of my code. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to halt flutter sdk updates while building. Sometimes some packages may cause issues to not build or show warnings, but it is not common for apps to slow down after updating. Flutter sdk will not be the problem. Is the app smooth after using `flutter downgrade`?

And please provide more information regarding this,

Is it the same for all devices?

Have you tried `flutter clean`?

Comment: Went for flutter downgrade but the app still lags. I have only one physical device, I am thinking that the app lags because the specs of my device is kinda low (but not that much). flutter clean did not help either.

Comment: Alright so we can confirm that flutter version isn't the issue here. Is the app smooth enough in release mode (`flutter run --releases`)?